# Start a process as sudo from a MacOS Swift App

Tags: swift, macos, sudo

I am very new to using Apple let alone developing an app for them, but looking at creating a simple app to learn the language a little bit.

I am trying to open a file in an app, but the app needs to be opened with admin rights. I've tested running in the command to prove the concept works by running the following:

```
sudo open /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf -a TextEdit
```

This as expected asks for the password in the terminal and then opens the app with the file to be editable.

I've then tried doing the following Swift to do the same thing:

```
let fileToOpen : String = txtFileToOpen.stringValue;
let task = Process();
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
        
task.arguments = ["sudo", "open", fileToOpen, "-a", "TextEdit"];
task.launch();
```

I was expecting that because I am running the above in app and not a terminal, that I would get the Apple dialog asking for my admin password to give permission for the above to run from my app, but unfortunately that doesn't work, instead I get the error:

> env: sudo: Operation not permitted

Is there a way I can do the above and prompt the admin password to allow my process to run from my app?

Comment: Actually you don't need admin privileges to **open** a file, On the other hand if your app is sandboxed there is no way to run operations with elevated rights.

Comment: You do if you want to be able to edit the file. That file is write protected without opening as sudo, which is a giant pain having to find the file in the terminal and then sudo it from the terminal to open it. I have no idea if my app is sandboxed, is that a default setting or something?

Comment: You didn't mention that you want to write into the file. In the latest version of Xcode sandbox is enabled by default. But even without the sandbox container it's not trivial to gain root privileges. You have to install a privileged helper.

Comment: Yea sorry I forgot to mention I was using sudo to make the file editable. I'll check out the privileged helper

Comment: "my app" being a desktop application submitted to Mac App Store or one for personal use?

Comment: I was planning for mac app store, but after reading up on what @vadian said I think I've pretty much given up on the idea. I forgot MacOS is a little more secure for things like that compared to windows :)